# Resized (Scale down) image jagged, smooth on redraw (not reload)

Tags: google-chrome, resize, scale, antialiasing

I scale an image down using css, but then its edges are jagged. However, if I quickly switch to another tab in chrome and then come back, it is drawn correctly. I assume that this is because of somethings that happens during redraw. Is there any way to force a redraw using jquery? I have tried adding classes, elements, and changing other attributes.

Comment: BUMP! Did anyone ever find a solution to this? I've just come up against this myself :(

Comment: I will post the solutions here. Give me a second. Thanks for the bump

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, thanks to the bump, I will add my solution here. What is really happening is we are trying to force a repaint of the entire window. The following does the trick:

```
function reDraw(){
    //hack to redraw the elements on the page to avoid choppy look of resized items
    //prevent reDraw from firing too early
    setTimeout(function(){$('body').hide().show(0)},66);   
}
```

The show hide combination will force a repaint of the area affected. note that the 0 on show is needed. The 66ms delay is used because forcing a repaint immediately after applying styles (in this case, a css resize) will bypass the recalculate styles function in the browser. 66ms is aprox. 15fps so it should still appear to happen instantaneously on any screen running at 30fps (it will take two screen refreshes if all goes well). A small blip from pixelated to non-pixelated is visible on a 60fps display, but how many people pay that close attention anyway?

Anyway, that is our solution. For us, it was used on a website that is built very similar to a video game as far as animation loop and other things. Because the screen is being refreshed a lot already, we found we only needed to call the reDraw function after the resizing of a PNG, but your requirements may be different.

Note that this function can be very resource intensive, and I have observed that many browsers need to collect garbage after this so you may need to evaluate how necessary the realtime aspect is. Use sparingly.

Enjoy!

~techdude

Comment: THANKYOU! This has been plaguing me for days, interestingly Chrome redraws scaled SVGs (in my case) when focus moves to another element, such as a hover-state link.